# Consultar registros de um mesmo mês

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite3

Estou tendo dificuldade em buscar no banco sqlite3, registros de um mês específico, procurei na internet porém não achei nada que pudesse me ajudar. Tenho um modelo Conta que tem belongs_to com a classe Situacao que é um enum onde tem status pendente ou pago. Gostaria de buscar no banco, contas que são de um mês específico e estejam pagas porém ainda não consegui filtrar. Alguma sugestão? Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar `Conta.where("created_at = ? AND situacao_id = ?", 1.month.ago, id_da_situacao)`

`"1.month.ago"` e `"id_da_situacao"` são os parâmetros usados na Query.

Comment: Obrigado, me deu uma base para que eu conseguisse entender melhor o problema e poder continuar no desenvolvimento da funcionalidade! Agradeço pela ajuda e pela atenção!